# How to migrate large mysql database where remote server has stringent limits?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, hosting

I have a local database thats about 1GB and my remote host is a free host that I am using for testing. want to make sure everything works before i spend money on a paid host. The problem is the phpmyadmin on the remote server only allows 50mb files which which just doesn't cut it, especially since the restore usually fails due to execution time limits. Below is the list of everything I've tried.

**LOCAL**

**phpmyadmin** -----> backingup of table no longer work because of timeout even with modified php.ini settings because of shear size of db

**mysqldumper** -----> program creates dumps with inserts, there is no option for me to make it create insert ignores. ill explain the problem later below.

**mysqlworkbench** -----> creates database using database name of my local server (problem is my remote server has a different database name and i cant open a 1gb .sql file to edit the database name at the very top. computer just craps out and I have to force quit workbench)

**sqlsplitter** (mac program) cuts up large .sql or .sql.gz files

**REMOTE**

**phpmyadmin** with .gz/.sql files cut up into 20mb chunks 
-----> timeout. phpmyadmin resume function doesnt work either. it just overwrites old data

**mysqldumper** -----> process ends up in an error randomly midway through my restore on remote server using a backup created with mysqldumper on my local computer (single file or multipart, both dont work). could be at 10% completion, could be at 50%.

**bigdump** -----> used single and multipart dumps from mysqldumper, same problem. randomly quits halfway through. some multiparts were successful in completing, but when one failed and I tried the failed part again, it would give me an error saying unique key already exists in table. i dont want to unset all my unique key stuff and have to go through and delete all duplicates later.

**mysqldumper** -----> does not work with dump from mysqlworkbench

**bigdump** -----> gives me an error sql error denied for creating database using dump from mysqlworkbench (i cannot open up a 1 gb file to delete that 1 line that says create database)

Does anybody know of a better method to upload to my host? I have no command line access on there and only a 500mb space limit (no limit on sql space though).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysqldump`.  Figure out what the error you're seeing is, and fix it.  The `mysqldump` utility **works**.  I've restored dumpfiles with hundreds of gigabytes of data to servers, and never use anything else.  If it doesn't work for you, you're doing something incorrectly.

You can prevent it from writing a `USE database-name;` statement at the top of the file by invoking it with the database name as the last argument, *without* using the `--databases` option before it.

You can add the `--insert-ignore` command line option to write all the `INSERT` statements as `INSERT IGNORE` to work around your partial insert issues

You can use `--no-data` to extract a dump file that contains table definitions, not data, and get all of the tables declared, first.

You can use the `--no-create-info` option to extract a dump file with just the inserts, not the table definitions.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html

You can also use a simple bash loop to extract each table into its own file, so you have smaller files to work with:

```
for TABLE in `mysql [args] -e 'show tables in database-name'`; do mysqldump [args] database-name $TABLE > $TABLE.sql; done
```

When restoring the files, add the `--compress` option to the `mysql` command line arguments for a faster transfer, and specify your (new) database name as the last argument, so the client will use the correct database before applying the file, which no longer contains the database name.

Comment: i ended up using mysqldump and it did indeed work. unfortunately i cannot use mysql for the upload because its a free shared host. but its ok, mysqldumper ended up importing with no problems. it gave me an error about setting the time or something at the end but all the data went in fine.

Comment: Actually, you can use `mysql` for the upload.  It's a client program, though the assumption that it's part of the server is a common misconception.  All you do is run it locally (not on the server) and use the `--host` option to tell it where to connect.

Comment: my free hosting has mysql remote connections disabled. =/ but interesting. i just invested a little money in a vps this afternoon instead and will definitely try that out. thanks!